# pandasで、複数列に対応するヘッダをCSVで出力したいです。

Tags: python, pandas

#### 実行環境

- pandas 0.25.3
- Python 3.7.4

#### やりたいこと

pandasのDataFramdeを使って、下図のような表をCSVとして出力したいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 試したこと

以下のPythonコードを実行しました。

```py
    dict_table = {("user1", "plan"): [1, 11], 
         ("user1", "work"): [2, 12],
         ("user2", "plan"): [3, 13],
         ("user2", "work"): [4, 14]
         }
    df = pandas.DataFrame(dict_table)
    df.to_csv("foo.csv", index=False)
```

出力結果(foo.csv)

```
user1,user1,user2,user2
plan,work,plan,work
1,2,3,4
11,12,13,14
```

#### 期待していた結果

本当は以下のように、ヘッダには同じユーザを一度しか表示しないフォーマットで出力したいです。

```
user1,,user2,
plan,work,plan,work
1,2,3,4
11,12,13,14
```

#### 質問

pandasを使って、上記のようなCSVは出力する方法を教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`levels` に空文字列(`''`)をセットした MultiIndex オブジェクトを作成して、df のインデックスにセットします。

```python
>>> midx = pd.MultiIndex(
  levels = [
    list(v) + [''] for v in df.columns.levels
  ],
  codes = [
    [
      y if n == 0 else
        (len(df.columns.levels[i]) if y == (list(v))[n-1] else y)
      for n, y in enumerate(list(v))
    ]
    for i, v in enumerate(df.columns.codes)
  ]
)

>>> midx
MultiIndex(levels=[['user1', 'user2', ''], ['plan', 'work', '']],
           codes=[[0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1]])

>>> df.T.set_index(midx).T.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**output.csv**

```python
user1,,user2,
plan,work,plan,work
1,2,3,4
11,12,13,14
```

**追記**

対象データはカラム数が少ないので、MultiIndex オブジェクトを手で書き下しても良いかと思います。

```python
>>> df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[['user1', 'user2'], ['plan', 'work']],
           codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

`df.columns.codes` で、同じインデックス番号が続く部分を変更します。以下のコードにおける、変更されている値 `2` は `levels[0][2]`(空文字) に対応しています。

```python
>>> df.T.set_index(
      pd.MultiIndex(
        levels = [['user1', 'user2', ''], ['plan', 'work']],
         codes = [[0, 2, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1]]
    )).T.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

**追記(2019/11/21)**

> to_csvメソッドなどのオプションなどでは対応できないのですね。

無理をすればできなくはないですが、お勧めはしません。

```python
import csv

output = StringIO()
df.to_csv(output,
  index      = False,
  header     = ['user1', '', 'user2', '\nplan,work,plan,work'],
  quoting    = csv.QUOTE_NONE,
  escapechar = '\01')

with open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  f.write(output.getvalue().replace('\01', ''))
```

`csv.QUOTE_NONE` を設定していますので、数値データのみの場合は問題ないのですが、`,`(カンマ/セパレータ)が含まれる文字列データの場合にはクォート処理が行われませんので、CSV としては不正なデータになってしまいます。

Comment: to_csvメソッドのなどのオプションなどでは対応できないのですね。

Answer (score 0):

ヘッダは`csv`で、データは`pandas`の追記モード指定で、別々に書くという考え方があります。

決め打ちで作るならファイルへの書き出し部分をこちらで：

```
import csv
csvfilename = 'foo.csv'
with open(csvfilename, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    # ヘッダ部を決め打ちで書き出し
    writer.writerows([['user1','','user2',''],['plan','work','plan','work']])

# データ部のみ追記
df.to_csv(csvfilename, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

DataFrameから動的に作る場合はこちらで：

```
import pandas
import csv

dict_table = {("user1", "plan"): [1, 11], 
     ("user1", "work"): [2, 12],
     ("user2", "plan"): [3, 13],
     ("user2", "work"): [4, 14]
     }
df = pandas.DataFrame(dict_table)

# DataFrameのheader部分を抽出してリスト化
dfhead = [list(x) for x in list(df.columns.values)]
lines = [len(v) for v in dfhead]
hdwork = []
for i in range(lines[0]):
    hdwork.append(sum([a[i:(i+1)] for a in dfhead], []))

# 各行内で直前と同じ文字列なら空文字列に変更
header = []
for row in hdwork:
    prev = ''
    rowwork = []
    for item in row:
        if item != prev:
            rowwork.append(item)
            prev = item
        else:
            rowwork.append('')

    header.append(rowwork)

# ヘッダ部書き出し
csvfilename = 'foo.csv'
with open(csvfilename, 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(header)

# データ部のみ追記
df.to_csv(csvfilename, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
```

---

**追記**
要求事項とは違いますが、いったん作った複数列データを使い回したいのでセーブしておきたい、読み込みも簡単にしたいと考えれば、[`to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) / [`read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) が使えるかもしれません。
ただし出来るexcelファイルは癖があってコレジャナイ感が強いですが。

使うのは単純に1行：

```
df.to_excel('foo.xlsx', header=[0,1])
```

出来たexcelファイルはこれなので、非常に違和感があります。
[image: to_excel()結果]

pandasドキュメントでは`index`を無くせるように見えますが、未実装あるいは想定していない使い方のようで`index=False`を指定するとエラーになります。
またヘッダ部とデータ部の間に空行が1行入ります。

しかし読み込みはこちらの1行で出来て、DataFrameの再現は簡単です。

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('foo.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

読み込んで出来たDataFrameは以下になります。

```
>>> df2
  user1      user2
   plan work  plan work
0     1    2     3    4
1    11   12    13   14
```

---

csvにこだわるならまた別の方法として、上記`to_excel()`/`read_excel()`に使われてそうな`openpyxl`の[`dataframe_to_rows()`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.dataframe.html)と`csv`を組み合わせるという手も考えられます。
こちらは`index`を消せるのですが、ヘッダ部とデータ部間の空行は残るのでちょっとした工夫が必要です。

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import csv

rows = dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False) # index無し指定が有効
csvframe = []
for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
    csvrow = []
    for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
        csvrow.append(value)

    if len(csvrow):        # 有効データのある行だけリストに追加
        csvframe.append(csvrow)

with open('foo.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(csvframe)
```